# Does iOS have IEnumerator Coroutines (C#) like stuff for async running tasks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

I was wondering if it is possible to use something like coroutine to delay some actions in iOS but WITHOUT freezing the hell out of the app? More specifically I want to make a MKMapView to update the location, but NOT AFTER USER INTERACTION and tell him to wait a bit. Since every answers I've found was kinda like if it updates it centers the view on user actual position, it works flawless, but as soon as I want to move away from the location it brings me back there. So I want to do something like okay, center the mapview to the current location, but if there was an interaction wait a few seconds and then you should move the view back. Is it possible?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation {
/*MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.latitude;
location.longitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.longitude;
region.span = span;
region.center = location;
[aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];*/
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:aUserLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
NSLog(@"Before sleep");
//[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:7];
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do your work here
});
NSLog(@"Fater sleep");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question, the answer is to use GCD `dispatch_after`:

```
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do your work here
});
```

This delayed call could be put in the handler for the user interaction.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation {

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
    dispatch_time_t delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // the mapView will center itself 5 seconds after didUpdateUserLocation is called
        [weakSelf.mapView setCenterCoordinate:aUserLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
    });
}
```

Comment: yep, that looks like it!

Comment: do you know also how I can delay another way the centering process at didUpdateUserLocation? because this is the only (but highly barbaric) method :D

Comment: Is the centering process built in to the didUpdateUserLocation, or do you manually call the centering method?

Comment: somewhat but no centering now unfortunately, but that's okay, I will make compromise in the app somehow :) thanks anyways bro!

Comment: Odd. I just built a small sample project using the above code. For me, the app opens, five seconds later the map centers on the user location. I did make a minor update to use __weak reference to self.